# How To Prevent Keyboard Being Closed After setState?

Tags: flutter

When the button clicked, the condition changes and `TextField` widget is removed from tree, but the keyboard is closed too. How to keep it open even after the TextField gone ?

```
bool someCondition;

initState(){
  someCondition = true;
}

...

Row(
   children:[
      someCondition ? TextField() : Text('How to keep keyboard open'),
      FlatButton(child: Text('Click me'), onPress: (){
        setState(() {
           someCondition = false;
        });
      })
   ],
)
```

Comment: `setState` reruns the build function which it is kinda like your app restarts, therefore i think it would be better if you do this with other state management system (such as bloc and redux ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Visibility` widget and maintain its state.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  bool someCondition = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Visibility(
                    visible: someCondition,
                    maintainAnimation: true,
                    maintainState: true,
                    maintainSize: true,
                    child: TextField(),
                  ),
                  if (!someCondition) const Text('How to keep keyboard open'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  someCondition = !someCondition;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Click me'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Magic of `Visibility` against `setState((){})`