# How to prevent Textfield rebuild when using the state of its FocusNode?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget like this:

```dart
class _CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const _CustomTextField();

  @override
  State<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      __CustomTextFieldState();
}

class __CustomTextFieldState extends State<_CustomTextField> {
  late final FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = FocusNode()..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      color: focusNode.hasFocus ? const Color(0xFFF5F5F5) : null,
      children: [
        if(focusNode.hasFocus)
          Icon(Icons.edit),
        TextField(
         focusNode: focusNode,
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

where I want to change the widget when the textfield gets selected.

My problem is, that with the current implementation, the whole widget gets rebuilt, causing the Keyboard to disappear immediately after selecting the textfield.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: You can give focused design to a textfield and you don't need to give styling like this.

Comment: Yeah, I actually gave a bad example (I have updated it) 
Basically I want to make changes, that can't be done with textfieldDecorations

Comment: This answer suggests that you can do it with the Visibility widget, whether this is the best way or not idk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910647/how-to-prevent-keyboard-being-closed-after-setstate - maybe valuenotifier/listener or some other dependency injection is the preferred route.